# Can't stop firing ASP.NET Module for static content

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a module in an ASP.NET MVC application. The module is working fine, but it's firing for every type of file including static content even though I have:

```
<modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <add name="MyModule" ... / >
</modules>
```

The module hooks AcquireRequestState and PostRequestHandlerExecute events and both show static content firing (.htm, .css, .png etc.).

I was under the impression that runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" should keep modules from firing on non-ASP.NET content.

To clarify:

I **can** set preCondition="managedHandler" like this:

```
<add name="MyModule" type="MyApp.MyModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

and get my module to fire only managed requests.

However, I'm trying to understand why the IIS pipeline in general is firing managed module hits for every request. I think this used to work just fine in older versions where unless runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" it wasn't firing unmanaged content into ASP.NET modules.

Running on IIS8 on Windows 8 64 bit mode, with integrated pipeline mode.

**Update:**

After some more research it turns out that the following is true:

- if runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" all modules - regardless of their preCondition attribute setting fire on all requests. This also true for Application_XXXX events implement on the HttpApplication
- runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" has no effect of keeping unmanaged requests from hitting modules, *unless* preCondition="managedHandler" is set
- runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" does affect Application_XXXX events, causing those events to only fire on managed requests then. IOW, Application_XXXX behaves as if the 'module' implementation had a preCondition="managedHandler"

For more detailed information on this I posted a blog entry:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Oct/25/Caveats-with-the-runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests-in-IIS-78

Comment: Can you check that StaticFileModule is registered under modules? Should point to %windir%\System32\inetsrv\static.dll

Comment: Just to sanity check, can you update with the full ancestry of the <modules> node? Should be under <system.webServer>. Like I said, sanity check. :)

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, you need preCondition="managedHandler" for modules -> add

Comment: @pbz - static file module is pointing at ISAPI path yes. Drew - I don't see anything 'odd' in the module list in IIS. I removed the MVC route handlers (extensionless, UrlRouting) just in case but same result.

Comment: It almost looks to me that IIS 8 is running EVERY request through the managed pipeline no matter what. I can even modify the default.htm content with Response.Write() which seems to indicate the .htm file is going through the ASP.NET pipeline and using the ASP.NET Response. If I rename to default.asp I still fire into the module, but Response.Write() has no effect presumably because ASP classic uses its own ISAPI based output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IIS7 Microsoft introduced a new way of developing modules and handlers by using managed (.NET) code, not just native code. Problem is switching a request between managed and native code is very expensive, so Microsoft introduced the `preCondition="managedHandler"`. It flags the module as only available for managed content requests (.aspx, .asmx, ...) so IIS avoids firing it for static content.

Now, you can have a situation where you want to modify an static content request, such as minifying JavaScript on the fly. You can write the module using C# and compile it as a managed module, but you want it to be fired for static content, so you simply do not mark it as `managedHandler`.

Finally, `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` is used to override `preCondition="managedHandler"` so all of them get fired.

There is more info available at:
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#Precondition

Comment: Sam - from what I understand IIS does not automatically fire managed code. But I suspect this might be true now - as soon as ANY managed module is on the pipeline maybe then it starts firing for all requests.
I'm more concerned about performance than the logic of things. The fact that static content fires into the managed pipeline would seem to add significant overhead to requests in general.