# How to stop OWIN Startup class for Identity Framework being called for image requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

Is it possible to stop the Owin Startup class from being called for every request to images within my `/Content/Images` folder?

I am finding that a new DbContext is being `new`ed up for every image request, when there doesn't need to be any authorization checks for images.

**UPDATE:**

I just created a brand new MVC project and I found that the class is not being called for images within `/Content/images/`.

So it looks as if, as the default, it doesn't call it when it is a request to the `/Content` folder, but for some reason in my application it does.

Is there a setting in the `web.config` or properties of the folder that configures this?

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that for static files. Do you have `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in your config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config, replace `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` with `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"`. If it breaks something in your application, you might have to fiddle with `preCondition="managedHandler"` on the registered modules, but most of the times the property should be set to `false`.

See [Can't stop firing ASP.NET Module for static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060678/cant-stop-firing-asp-net-module-for-static-content) for details on how this property works.

Comment: This is the answer. You don't want static files, firing up the entire ASP.NET Stack.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much for your help.  I added this when I started configuring ImageProcessor for .NET - but after a little bit of testing it looks like it works without it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with something like this and not call your config if IsStaticContent=true (I used this in global.asax but will be the same):

```
readonly string[] _staticContents = { ".js", ".css", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".html", ".htm", ".gif", ".ashx", ".axd" };

protected bool IsStaticContent(HttpRequest request)
{

    return _staticContents.Any(request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.EndsWith);
}
```